# Dados sensíveis em persistence.xml

Tags: jpa, jpa-2.0

Estou usando JPA em minha aplicação e por isso tenho um arquivo `persistence.xml` que contém os dados de conexão com o meu banco de dados:

```
<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost/banco" />
<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="admin" />
<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="123456" />
<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
<property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect" />
```

Eu não gostaria de *commitar* senhas e usuários em texto puro, por isso gostaria de saber se alguém conhece alguma alternativa ELEGANTE para gerenciar os dados sensíveis da minha aplicação, algum mecanismo de encriptação, por exemplo.

Comment: Se for usar a solução junto com um sistema de versionamento, recomendo uma olhada neste projeto, que por acaso, é da StackExchange mesmo: https://github.com/StackExchange/blackbox

Comment: Se utilizar um container enterprise JavaEE full a configuração e o gerenciamento fica  a cargo do container, se usa Tomcat também usar [JNDI](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html#JNDI_Resource_Naming_and_Realm_Interaction) para nomear esses recursos

Comment: Acho que JNDI nesse caso seria o ideal pra mim. Prefiro deixar a cargo do container (tomcat) esse controle dos dados sensíveis. Obrigada pelas dicas! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolvido utilizando JNDI. Prefiro deixar a cargo do container (tomcat) esse controle dos dados sensíveis.